# HID actividentity keychain token locked

Tags: token, hid, one-time-password, two-factor-authentication, aaa-security-protocol

I have a hardware actividentity keychain token.
The pin was entered wrong many times continuously and the token is locked.
When it is switched on it just displays the serial number for few seconds and goes off.
How to unlock this token now.
The serial number is not accepted as challenge code when tried to unlock using the administrator ui.

Is there any way to unlock the token.